# Range of port needed on given list

Tags: shell, sorting, range

I have a list of ports and I want to print a range out of it as below. Range should be +/- 10 values on output

Port list

```
8983,8985,8983,8985,9983,8993,8987,8997,8995,9854,9985,9975,9976,9977,9978,9979,9980,9997,9987,9995,9993,8925,2181,2189,2185,2187,2183,2191,2193,2195
```

**
Tried sorting it but range logic needed.
**

```
tr , '\n' < list.txt > port_list.txt
sort -n port_list.txt | uniq > sorted_list.txt
```

Output needed as

```
2181 - 2195
8925
8983 - 8997
9854
9975 - 9997
```

Comment: `Range should be +/- 10 values` What does that mean?

Comment: Output range should not be grater than or less than 10. 
No need of extra range of ports. If the port is nearer to +/- 10 of previous port then we can make it as range.

Comment: `2181 - 2195` isn't greater? That's 14... Should it be splitted on two? Anyway, you have a sorted list of unique numbers. So read one number (in awk or in bash), see if the current number is greater then 1 from the previous one - if it is, it means it's a range, increment some var and read next line - if it isn't, output the cached/"previous" range if any and the number becomes the current range start. There are many great awk tutorials available on the net. It is greatly appreciated on this forum to show what research did you do? what have you tried? where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: 2181
2183
2185
2187
2189
2191
2193
2195      ----> All those numbers doesn't have much range difference. So we can club as 2181 - 2195 . If we have a number as 2187, 2190,  2195 &  2207 output should be 2187 - 2195 & 2207

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU awk (because `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"`). It loses duplicates but I don't see why wouldn't it:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                         # hash all values to a hash
        a[$i]
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"       # process in ascending order
    for(i in a) {
        if(p=="") {                            # new row starts
            printf "%s%d",(j++==0?"":ORS),p=i 
            continue
        }
        if((i-p)<10) {                         # 10 hardcoded here
            p=i                                # buffer to p if smaller
        } else {                               # or output if bigger
            printf " - %d\n%d",p,i
            p=""
        }
    }
    if(p)                                      # cleanup after last value
        printf " - %d\n",p
    else
        print ""
}' file
```

Output:

```
2181 - 2195
8925
8983 - 8997
9854
9975 - 9997
```